# UTF8.GetString() returns a string (which is UTF-16)

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

string (System.String) is UTF-16, but if I convert a string to UTF-8, the Encoding.UTF8.GetString() method returns AGAIN string (UTF-16), and it's imposible, because string isn't UTF-8.

```
var foo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("hello"));
Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType()); // Prints "System.String"
```

Comment: So what's your question? So far this is a handful of statements.

Comment: A method that returns UTF-8 chars returns a string (and string is UTF-16). I converted a string (UTF-16) to UTF-8 and I received a string again (UTF-16).

Comment: The type `string` is internally UTF-16. Don't understand how you expect to become UTF8? UTF-8 can be the encoding of `byte` array of file contents, but not value of `string` type variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `String` is always UTF-16. If you convert a String to a String you'll either get the same string or data loss.

You can convert a String to a byte array using any available or custom encoding. In most cases, especially writing a file, you can just tell the writer or stream which encoding you want *it* to use.

---

In case there is any confusion about UTF-16 and UTF-8, they are both encodings for the same character set: Unicode. There is no data loss between them; you'd just use the most appropriate one, typically UTF-16 in memory and UTF-8 for files and streams.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzb9f993(v=vs.110).aspx
As you can see, the method that convert to UTF-8 returns STRING, not *something* UTF-8.

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. It takes UTF-8 encoded text (Byte array) and returns UTF-16 encoded text (String).

Comment: @JoeDay `Encoding.GetString` converts **from** encoding. `Encoding.GetBytes` converts **to** encoding.